# Getting a value from a text box in php without using a form element in HTML

Tags: php, textbox

I need to get a value from a text box, but I'm not using a form, therefore I can't use $_POST or $_GET. Is there any method to get that value from the text box? Below is the code that I'm using

```
<input name="txtQty" type="text" id="txtQty" size="5" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" onKeyUp="checkNumber(this);"> //here I'm the displaying the quantity, then the user can change it, and I need to get that value to pass it throught this link: 

<input name="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" onClick="window.location.href='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=update&cid=$shoppingCartId&qty=$qty //here I need that new value from the textbox"; ?>';"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: why are you not using a form?

Comment: AJAX is your only option without using a form ... but why no form ?

Comment: You need some JS, but doing a simple form with hidden inputs for the `action` and `cid`, and just name the qty input `qty`, would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this without a page refresh you need javascript. If you do have a page refresh, you need a form.

Comment: He/she needs the value to put inside the button tag.

Answer (score 1):

Without form or javascript controlled request - no you can't

Answer (score 1):

Ajax must be used to Pass client data to sever if not wish to refresh the page. Check below code, which was written with simple changes.

```
 <input name="txtQty" type="text" id="txtQty" size="5" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>"> 
 <input name="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" id="btnEdit" onclick="redirectUser()"  />

<script>

 function redirectUser(){
     var qty = document.getElementById('txtQty').value;
     location.replace('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>action=update&cid=<?php echo $shoppingCartId; ?>&qty='+qty);
 }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP only runs on the server, so the only way to get the values from your inputs would be to somehow pass them to the server.

You could do it in a number of ways, but the easiest would likely be to put your inputs into a form, and post the form to a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript:

```
document.getElementById("txtQty").value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, So how can assign that javascript variable to $qty?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saving text box box variable in php?
If you are passing value to text box in php, then you can echo php value over there.

```
<input name="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" onClick="window.location.href='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=update&cid=$shoppingCartId&qty="+<?php echo $qty; ?>';"
```

If not then you can use directly form item as value over there.

```
<input name="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" onClick="window.location.href='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=update&cid=$shoppingCartId&qty="+document.getElementById("txtQty").value';"
```